# Algorithm to find the square root

Tags: c, algorithm, square-root

Playing around with formulas in C, I realized that I found a formula for calculating the square root of a number. I would like to know if such an algorithm already exists, or if it is widely known to scholarly mathematicians. I'm sending the code so you guys take a look. I tested it in C++ Builder with TimeSpan and it is almost as fast as the language's standard sqrt function, which is written in assembly. If you can take a look and see if this is interesting I would appreciate it. It's for a school assignment.

Ps: for most numbers it gets the precision of the sqrt function to about 20 iterations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int findInitial(double number){

    int i,n,res;
    n = trunc(number);
    res = 0;
    i = 1;
    while (1){
        if ((i * i) >= n) {
           res = i - 1;
           break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    double number = 23;
    int initial = findInitial(number);
    double f = number;
    double e;
    double temp = 1;
    
    printf("%.18f\n",sqrt(number));

    while ((temp < -0.000000000000000001) ^ (temp > 0.000000000000000001)){
        e = f - (f * f - number)/(f - initial);
        if (temp == ((f - e) * -1)) {
          break;
        }
        temp = f - e;
        f = e;
        i++;
        printf("%d - %.18f\n",i,f*-1);
    }

    system("pause");    
    return 0;
}
```

Ps2: I had to create a conditional because in the case of number 23, the variable temp oscillated from negative to positive and never reached the desired precision.

Comment: this looks like a basic variant of Newton's method that's not guaranteed to converge

Comment: `int n = trunc(number);` is UB when `trunc(number)` is much more than `INT_MAX`.

Comment: You want to check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root ; your code is a bit ummm obfuscated, but what you really do is "next iterations's `f` is last iteration's `f` minus f²-number), divided by a factor proportional to the derivative of x²-a. This is really Newton's method with unclean notation.

Comment: this doesn't necessarily converge. Newton converges for all strictly positive numbers. The lack of guaranteed convergense is due to the bad choice of divisor; should be `2*f`instead of `f-initial`.

Comment: You have indeed re-invented Newton's method. For a quadratic equation it will work nicely, unless there is a double root. Your stopping test could be more elegant if you used `std::numeric_limits`. Maybe you can eliminate the oscillation test by starting always to the right of the root.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks. I hadn't spotted that. So it's an "over-relaxed" Newton's method in many cases.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout `std::numeric_limits` is [tag:C++], but this is [tag:C].

Comment: _"almost as fast as the language's standard sqrt function"_   - that seems unlikely, the FPU has a `FSQRT` instruction - the  standard library implementation operation is performed in hardware.  You might usefully post a question about your test method, it is clearly flawed.  If you measured the exact code posted in your question, then what you were measuring is dominated by the `printf()` call which will be many orders of magnitude longer than either your algorithm or `sqrt()`.

Comment: @Clifford It wasn't this code that I tested, it was one that I tested in the C++ Builder compiler using the methods I researched on the Embarcadero website. (I took the printfs out) but I really don't know if my way of testing is correct. I simply put a variable of type TStopwatch, initialized it with the StartNew() method and after the function I gave a Stop(). I initialized a variable of type TTimeSpan, took the Elapsed time and called the Ticks method. Gave a similar number. Maybe the sqrt() function is so fast that it can't calculate right.

Comment: Testing a single call is unlikely to give an accurate impression. You should perhaps call the code iteratively, say 10000 calls.  The resolution of TTimeSpan.ticks() is 100ns which is significant cf to a single instruction cycle.  Generally if you make an assertion about a test you have performed, that is the code you should post.  With respect to sqrt() being written in assembler; the machine code generated from C compilation is often just as fast (if optimised); there is nothing magically fast about assembly code, its speed is in the hands of the author, and the compiler optimized is expert.

Comment: Your `find initial` is much much slower than binary based sqrt ... so you most likely did not measure it properly ... there is no way this is faster than FPU instruction... see [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) and try [tbeg(),tend() from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70142282/2521214) for the time measurement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from this not working for all legal inputs (so it's, strictly speaking, *not* a method for finding the square root of numbers in general, just for *a few* of the possible numbers), this is basically Newton's method for approximating the square root.

Using Newton's method for this is like *the* standard example for a numerical math lecture, so Wikipedia has a concrete section on [Newton's Method for finding Square Roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root).

Your method is not *quite* Newton's method, because the convergence of that works for all inputs, by the fortune of dividing by the derivative of the function you want to find a null of (which is `f*f-number` in your case).

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I took a look at the proposed wiki and it's definitely Newton's method with a bad derivative. Also Newton's method converges faster. I don't know if it converges for all the numbers either, at least the ones I tested do.

Comment: @vanzuita that's the good thing, the math *guarantees* it converges :) f²-number fulfills the conditions on the continuity, absence of further nulls, and bounding of derivative that it does for all strictly positive numbers. :)