# pi finding algorithm works for first few iterations then starts returning 0

Tags: go, math, trigonometry

I've written an algorithm to find pi by inscribing a square within a circle of diameter 1 so that the diagonal bisector of the square is of length 1. This gives me 4 right angle triangles with side length 0.5 that I can use cosine law on to find the perimeter of the square. By halving each angle and keeping the side length of each triangle 0.5, I can indefinitely increase the number of sides of the inside square so that it approaches the shape of the circle around it, which has perimeter 1(pi) since the diameter is one.

The problem is that when I run my code it starts to approach pi until it sends a "4" and then every output becomes 0, what am I doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func findpi(angle, numsides float64) float64 {

    /*here i use cosine law to find the length of the c side of each inner triangle
      and multiply by the number of these inner triangles to find the perimeter*/

        return math.Sqrt(0.5-0.5*(math.Cos(angle*math.Pi/180))) * numsides
}

func main() {

    /*and here i halve the inner angle of the 4 triangles in the square repeatedly 
      as well as double the # of sides to approach a circle with perimeter pi*/

    for angle, numsides := 90.0, 4.0; angle > 0.000000001; angle, numsides = angle/2, numsides*2 {

        fmt.Println(findpi(angle, numsides))

    }

}
```

Comment: just few sanity checks (unrelated to the actual question): 1. you are using PI  (`angle*math.Pi/180`) to find PI ?  2. if you can use goniometrics (which usually uses PI internally too) then why iterate at all? You could simply do `PI = 4*acos(sqrt(0.5))` real PI computation its done with functions and constants that do not use PI like [Taylor series based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22295383/2521214), [PSLQ based BPP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56035284/2521214) etc ... The closest one to your approach is this stochastic [Monte Carlo approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70142282/2521214)

Comment: however that one is converging very slowly which is also related to your saturation of float precision issue

Answer (score 0):

This part `math.Cos(angle2)` is getting close to 1 and at some point you start to loose precision. Float64 is not the right type. You may need to use math/big however I can’t find an example with cosine.

Perhaps you can define the first N terms of Taylor’s series