# Separate float into digits

Tags: python, string, list

I have a float:

```
pi = 3.141
```

And want to separate the digits of the float and put them into a list as intergers like this:

```
#[3, 1, 4, 1]
```

I know to to separate them and put them into a list but as strings and that doesnt help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is PI calculated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654749/how-is-pi-calculated)

Comment: a float does not really decimal digits, it has binary digits, The decimal digits of your `pi` could equally well be `3.1410000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625`

Comment: (try `'%.100f' % 3.141`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to loop through the string representation of the number and check if the number is a digit. If yes, then add it to the list. This can be done by using a list comprehension.

```
>>> pi = 3.141
>>> [int(i) for i in str(pi) if i.isdigit()]
[3, 1, 4, 1]
```

Another way using Regex (Not - preffered)

```
>>> map(int,re.findall('\d',str(pi)))
[3, 1, 4, 1]
```

A final way - Brute force

```
>>> pi = 3.141
>>> x = list(str(pi))
>>> x.remove('.')
>>> map(int,x)
[3, 1, 4, 1]
```

Few references from the docs

- [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)
- [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#performing-matches)
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

The `timeit` results

```
python -m timeit "pi = 3.141;[int(i) for i in str(pi) if i.isdigit()]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.56 usec per loop
python -m timeit "s = 3.141; list(map(int, str(s).replace('.','')))" # Avinash's Method
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.54 usec per loop
python -m timeit "import re;pi = 3.141; map(int,re.findall('\d',str(pi)))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.72 usec per loop
python -m timeit "pi = 3.141; x = list(str(pi));x.remove('.'); map(int,x);"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.48 usec per loop
```

As you can see the brute force method is the fastest. The Regex answer as known is the slowest.

Comment: i tried the brite force methode caus i didint understood the other two u showed, but the list still came out as a list of strings not integers:


    x = list(str(number))
    x.remove('.')
    map(int,x)

    return x

(number is pi)

result:

['3', '1', '4', '1', '5', '9', '2', '6', '5', '3', '5', '9']

Comment: @JoJo I'm sure you have missed the last statement. That is `map(int,x)`

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `string.replace` along with `map`, `list` functions.

```
>>> s = 3.141
>>> list(map(int, str(s).replace('.','')))
[3, 1, 4, 1]
```

Comment: i think it's because your code checks for each char is a digit or not.