# how to split the digits of pi into a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am plotting the digits of pi on a matplotlib graph, however in order to do this I must split the digits into individual integers. I am using math.pi for this, is there any other way I could do it to make it easier?

I think .split() only works on strings however I may be wrong.

Comment: How do you mean *split the digits into individual integers*?

Comment: You have a float and would like to split the digits into a list?

Comment: Turns 3.1415 into [3, 1, 4, 1, 5]

Comment: `math.pi` won't give you many digits. Here is a function that will return as many digits as you want, in a string: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40834329/4996248

Comment: Exact dupe of [Separate float into digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770437/separate-float-into-digits)

Comment: convert number to string and then you can do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that strings have a `.split()` method and doubles do not.

I think you are thinking about the number as a string, though.  Numbers don't really have separate digits, except in their textual representation in some base.  So, you could convert the number to a string and go from there.

Eg.

```
text = "%.20f" % math.pi
digits = [int(s) for s in text if s != "."]
print(digits)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to split each digit into a list? If so, I would convert it to a string (since numbers are treated as the number itself and not digits that make it up) Then remove the decimal point by making a list that excludes decimal points.

```
import math

listOfDigits = [item for item in str(math.pi) if item != "."]
```

Comment: loose the `list()`, `str()` is iterable

Comment: Or `list(str(math.pi).replace('.', ''))`

Comment: that is also a valid way to do it.

Comment: Somebody downvoted it - may I ask what was bad about my answer? So that I can improve next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a generator:

```
def split_number(number):
    number_as_string = str(number)
    for character in number_as_string:
        if not character.isdigit():
            continue
        yield int(character)

import math
print(list(split_number(math.pi)))
# [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 9]
```

Or if you prefer a one-liner:

```
list(int(character) for character in str(math.pi) if character.isdigit())
# or
[int(character) for character in str(math.pi) if character.isdigit()]
```

I believe these answers are preferable because of the use of `isdigit` instead of special-casing only the `.` character.